# Problems with my adaptive video div

Tags: css, html, video

Basically what I am trying to achieve is a video that fills a div, then when the window size is reduced to that of a mobile it will resize smaller in the div. However, the original video is way larger than the div so i need to resize it. If i put the video to 100% width it effects the smaller video so it doesn't switch when the window is made smaller, so i think i need max width on the video perhaps? But ive tried it and its not altering the size at all.

My structure is

Im not super advanced at html/css yet so please keep it basic :)

Many thanks.

```
<div id="video_1">

<video id='myvideo'controls > 


<source src="video/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 480px), all               and (max-device-width: 480px)"> 
<source src="video/small.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width: 480px), all and (max-device-width: 480px)"> 
<source src="video/small.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="all and (max-width: 480px), all  and (max-device-width: 480px)"> 

<source src="video/large.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
<source src="video/large.webm" type="video/webm"> 
<source src="video/large.ogv" type="video/ogg"> 


fallback here



</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the related code here.

Comment: Have just updated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code will keep your video in proportion and scale it accordingly. 

 Be sure to place your video inside a container div.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop>   
        <source src="backgroundmovie.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="backgroundmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
video { 
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want  to make it responsive, add a media query and set the video's parent div width and height to whatever you like. This will make the video automaticly jump to 100% height/width of the parent container when the browser is scaled.